# Convert Height to Inches (Java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am having issues with the output of my code. Seems I am missing something in my method that I created... I had instructions to return the total number of inches. I places totInches after return and get an error stating that totInches is not a variable. Not certain what is missing here as I am only supposed to be creating a method. Most of this code was written and the only portion I was supposed to created was the second convertToInches method.. Any advice?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FunctionOverloadToInches {

   public static double convertToInches(double numFeet) {
      return numFeet * 12.0;
   }

   public static double convertToInches(double numFeet, double numInches) {
      return totInches * 12.0;
   }

   public static void main (String [] args) {
      double totInches = 0.0;

      totInches = convertToInches(4.0, 6.0);
      System.out.println("4.0, 6.0 yields " + totInches);

      totInches = convertToInches(5.9);
      System.out.println("5.9 yields " + totInches);
      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: It may be but the majority of the code is uneditable in the software our class runs it in so I am only allowed to edit what is given to me and that is the section "   public static double convertToInches(double numFeet, double numInches) {
      return totInches * 12.0;
   }
"

Comment: the variable `totInches` in your `convertToInches` method is not declared, its in the main method which your method has no access to. In other words, `totInches` in `convertToInches` has no scope, or is `null` probably

Comment: Work the problem in your head, first. How do you calculate inches, given a figure for feet and another for additional inches? Look to the convertToInches(double numFeet) method as a guide. You're not experiencing a Java or programming problem, but rather, one of conceptualizing the task at hand.

Comment: I see what you are saying, If I declare totInches I get an error stating                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "non-static variable totInches cannot be referenced from a static context
      return totInches;"                                                                                                                          Not certain why im seeing an error when it is now a variable :/

Comment: Thank you I will walk the steps through in my head and see if I can get it here. My logic must be off lol

Answer (score 2):

The variable `totInches` is not defined in the scope of your function:

```
public static double convertToInches(double numFeet, double numInches) {
  return totInches * 12.0;
}
```

The only variables you can use in this function are the ones you create and the ones defined as formal parameters: `numFeet` and `numInches`. So you have to come up with an equation that takes `numFeet` and converts it to inches, taking into account the additional inches provided in `numInches`.

Comment: I got it!!!! `public static double convertToInches(double numFeet, double numInches) {
      return numFeet * 12 + 6;
   }`

Comment: Getting there! What about `numInches`?

Comment: I thought I was going to need to do something for that but my code went through and passed all of the checks. Not certain why they had me use numInches in my second method lol

Comment: Just because you pass the tests doesn't mean your code is correct -- your tests might not be testing all possible cases!

Answer (score 0):

You declared the double variable "totInches" inside of your main method, but you are trying to access it inside of your "convertToInches" method. When declaring a variable in a particular method, that variable is ONLY accessible by that method. Your "convertToInches" knows of only two variables: numFeet and numInches, which you passed to it in the parameter. It then looks at your return statement, sees "totInches" and has no idea what it is.

I also don't understand what this is trying to do...

```
     public static double convertToInches(double numFeet, double numInches) {
      return totInches * 12.0;
   }
```

Why are you passing it the double variables numFeet and numInches? The function isn't using them. I also don't understand why you need both the number of feet AND **the number of inches** if the method, by its name, is trying to convert something into inches.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static double convertToInches(double numFeet, double numInches) {
      return (numFeet * 12) + numInches;
```

This takes into account any variable amount entered by user for height of `5` feet `7` inches or `6` feet even